# Rsamtools error when loading packages

Tags: r, bioconductor

when I want to load Rsamtools package in R I see the error as bellow :

```
  Error in get(method, envir = home) : 
    lazy-load database'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rsamtools/      R/Rsamtools.rdb' is corrupt
  In addition: Warning messages:
  1: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
    restarting interrupted promise evaluation
  2: In get(method, envir = home) :
    restarting interrupted promise evaluation
  3: In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
  Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rsamtools’
```

and the output of sessionInfo is :

```
  R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
  Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
  Running under: OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)

  locale:
  [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

  attached base packages:
  [1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets        methods  
  [9] base     

  other attached packages:
   [1] UniProt.ws_2.8.0     RCurl_1.95-4.6       bitops_1.0-6               RSQLite_1.0.0       
   [5] DBI_0.3.1            BiocInstaller_1.18.2 Biostrings_2.36.1    XVector_0.8.0       
   [9] AnnotationDbi_1.30.1 Biobase_2.28.0       GenomicRanges_1.20.4       GenomeInfoDb_1.4.0  
  [13] IRanges_2.2.3        S4Vectors_0.6.0      BiocGenerics_0.14.0 

  loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] zlibbioc_1.14.0 tools_3.2.0     biomaRt_2.24.0  XML_3.98-1.2
```

not only I can't use Rsamtools but also when I want to use my old packages which I could use them before some error occures as bellow for example for using "TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene" package :

```
  Loading required package: GenomicFeatures
  Error in get(method, envir = home) : 
    lazy-load database       '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rsamtools/R/Rsamto      ols.rdb' is corrupt
  In addition: Warning messages:
  1: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
    restarting interrupted promise evaluation
  2: In get(method, envir = home) :
    restarting interrupted promise evaluation
  3: In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1                          Error: package ‘GenomicFeatures’ could not be loaded
```

what should I do?

Comment: Did you run `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`? Also, you should run `source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite()`.

Comment: Yes I do it now, and nothing changed. errors are the same as before

Comment: when use command biocLite() it recognize 'BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19' is an old package but I always refeused to update this package because it is about 600M and my internet connection is not so fast. Do you think the reson of error is old version of 'BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19' ?

Comment: Try to specify the package: `biocLite("Rsamtools")`. Also, according to this page, `BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19` is suggested.

Comment: I used biocLite("Rsamtools") but the problem have not been solved

Comment: So you probably really need to upgrade all the bioconductor packages.

Comment: Remove Rsamtools first, `remove.packages("Rsamtools")` repeat several times until R says that there is no package Rsamtools, in case there are multiple versions installed. Try installation again with `biocLtie("Rsamtools")`. Try biocValid() and following the suggestions -- 'release' versions of *bioc* packages have even minor version numbers, but your installation has a mix of even and odd versions and so mixes packages from release and devel. The BSgenome package is not likely the immediate source of your problem. Do all of this trouble-shooting from the console starting R with `R --vanilla`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surprisingly!restarting the session solved the problem :|

Comment: Ditto, same issue and same solution.

Comment: Same issue and same solution!! I just wanna say, WTF.